# Protect image contents from unauthorised people

Tags: php, imagick

We all know, this is a very important issue for many web developers. They want to protect direct access or direct readability to their confidential images. The folder that contains all the images is open and anyone can visit that folder, but I want to do something that can protect my image contents, means, if an unauthorised guy looks for an image he may get the image by visiting the appropriate folder but the contents will be invisible or difficult to understand. I think if I get a solution here, many guys will be helped from this question. Writing `.htaccess` isn't always a stable choice. So, after brainstorming I found some ways how I can protect image contents from direct access. I want to use `Imagick` with `PHP` to perform any kind of image editing.

1. **Adding and removing a layer:** After uploading, add a layer to make contents of the image invisible. So, if anyone reaches the folder you've stored the images will be meaningless as he will see the layer not the image content. Then remove the layer and show to them who have proper rights.
2. **Converting the image to another format:** Convert the image to any format like .txt, .exe, .bin, .avi or any other format so that without editing, the image won't be visible. Convert back to show it to the authorised user.
3. **Image grid:** Divide the image into some grids, say, if the image is medium 100 grids and change the position of the grids to make the contents unclear. To do this, we can name each grid like 1, 2, 3 and so on, then change the position to `$position - 20`. So the grid of position 25 will go to 5, 100 will go to 80, 1 will go to 81 and so on. Reverse the same way to display to the authorised users.

It is never possible to protect completely but we can make it harder. I don't know which of the three is possible with `Imagick` and which is not. Please tell me if you know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you also considered placing the images in a folder outside the root of your web site. This way only people have to go through your website to access the images.

Comment: Are you writing an image uploading web app that allow your users to upload images? Or are you simply wanting to protect against hotlinking and stealing images by right-clicking? Image grid sounds nice, but I would use encryption instead. Or, you can store your image into a MySQL blob.

Comment: jeff, great idea. SHiNKiROU, I'm not protecting saving image, rather than making contents difficult to understand. Yes users and admin will upload images. Would you lease explain or refer to an article regarding encryption?

Comment: What on earth led you to the conclusion that ".htaccess isn't always a stable choice"? Also, more generally: Who are you trying to prevent from doing what here?

Answer (score 2):

You can put these images in a different folder outside of the public_html (so nobody can access them). Then via script, if a user is logged in, you get the image file content and then change the header. If a user is not logged, you can display a random image or showing a default image.

for example, the public html folder is: `/var/www your image folder can be: /registered_user/images/`

Then in your PHP script you can write:

```
<?php
if(!userLogged() || !isset($_GET['image'])) {
  header('Location: /');
  die();
}
$path = '/registered_user/images/';
$file = clean($_GET['image']); // you can create a clean function that only get valid character for files

$filename = $path . $file;
if(!file_exists($filename)) {
  $filename = '/var/www/images/bogus.jpg';
}
$imageInfo = getimagesize($filename);

header ('Content-length: ' . filesize($filename));
header ('Content-type: ' . $imageInfo['mime']);
readfile ($filename);
```